# Security Exception accessing Content Provider in another application

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to create a content provider usable only by the applications that are signed by the same certificate.
I've declared the content provider like this

```
<provider
    android:name=".MyProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.provider"
    android:permission="com.example.permissions.USER_PERMISSION"
        android:readPermission="com.example.permissions.USER_PERMISSION_READ"
        android:writePermission="com.example.permissions.USER_PERMISSION_WRITE"
        android:exported="true">
</provider>
```

I have declared the permissions with signature protection level.

All good but when I try to access the provider from the other application like this:

```
   //Create an URI that will be used to check the status of the content provider
    Uri myURI = Uri.parse("content://com.example.provider");
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    try {
        contentResolver.insert(prototypeURI,null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get a `SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provide ... requires com.example.permissions.USER_PERMISSION_READ`.

Any ideas?

Comment: take read or write permission in your android mainifest file

Comment: I did, they are both there

Comment: Are running on 6.0 or >? then you have to ask run-time permissions.

Comment: Running on Android 5.1, cyanogen Mod, One plus One

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
One of the application used a different debug key set through the gradle.build signing configuration.

Answer (score 1):

First, either use `android:permission` *or* the combination of `android:readPermission` and `android:writePermission`.

Second, the app with the `<permission>` elements defining those permissions needs to be installed first.

Third, the other app needs corresponding `<uses-permission>` elements for the necessary permissions.